# Unexpected output but expected view when using hooks React for toggle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to create a toggle function using hooks, one page is the edit page, another page is the view.

The below gives me the expected visual output i.e. when click Edit shows edit, when click View shows View. However the console logs show what's going on underneath is wrong.
Please help?

```
export default function EditProfileToggle (props) {
  const [showEdit, showView] = useState(true);



    if(showEdit) {
      console.log("showEdit")
    }

    if(showView){
      console.log("showView")
    }

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>

      <View style={{flexDirection: "row", paddingHorizontal: 80}}>
        <View>
          <Button title="Show Edit" onPress={()=>{showView(true)}} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button title="Show View" onPress={()=>{showView(false)}} />
        </View>
      </View>


      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {showEdit && <EditScreenToggle /> || showView && <ViewScreenToggle/> }
      </View>

    </View>

  )
}


export function EditScreenToggle () {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <EditScreen />
    </View>
  )
}

export function ViewScreenToggle () {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ViewScreen />
    </View>
  )
}
```

I expected to show Edit Screen when show Edit is true and View screen when show View is true. However when on the Edit Screen I get from the console:
"showEdit"
"showView"

When I click on the View button I get "showView"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the useState hook

The first value in the array (here showEdit) is the value, which is stored in the state.

The second value (here showView) is actually the function to set the state and should be named toggleView.

showView is always true, since its a function and your console.log will be called every time.

Rename showView and only check if showEdit is true like this:

```
{showEdit ? <EditScreenToggle /> : <ViewScreenToggle/> }
```

This will show EditScreenToggle if showEdit  is true. If not ViewScreenToggle will be visible.

Hope this helps.